# Dynamic Top horizontal menu is not working properly, when bootstrap dropdown class is added to last <li>

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a top horizontal menu which is dynamic and should cover maximum width of Screen, in spite of how many tab are available there.

Below you can see an example.

In this menu, No. of tabs One, Two, Three, Four and Five may vary. It may only four, or three of two. and should cover full width of screen.
and, last Menu definitely will contain Drop down type.
But drop down is not getting displayed on click, when position of last

child is not absolute.
when i put position of last

child as absolute then drop down is getting displayed. But width of Menu get reduced. 
I want to display drop down without getting menu width reduced.
please help.

```css
#main-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#main-nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0.09em;
}

#main-nav li:first-child {
  width: 18.35%;
}

#main-nav li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  width: 11%;
}

#main-nav li a {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 37px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#465f8d, #2b3c5b);
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

#main-nav li a:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#1f7c5f, #2b3c5b);
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

#main-nav li a:focus {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#fc6f37, #cb3e06);
  color: #ffffff;
}

#main-nav li a p {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-close-others="true" href="#">five</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>ABC</li>
        <li>DEF</li>
        <li>JKL</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Removed jsfiddle and insert code into code snippet since it runs there without any problem to make code sample directly testable by running it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: auto;` on `#main-nav`.

```css
#main-nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
#main-nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 0.09em;

}
#main-nav li:first-child {
  width:18.35%;
}
/*
#main-nav li:last-child {
    position:absolute;
  width:11%;
}
*/
#main-nav {
  overflow: auto;  
}

#main-nav li a {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 37px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image:linear-gradient(#465f8d,#2b3c5b);
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
}
#main-nav li a:hover {
    background-image:linear-gradient(#1f7c5f,#2b3c5b);
    color: #e0e0e0;
}
#main-nav li a:focus {
  background-image:linear-gradient(#fc6f37,#cb3e06);
  color: #ffffff;
}
#main-nav li a p {
  margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-close-others="true" href="#">five</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li >ABC</li>
     <li >DEF</li>
      <li >JKL</li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```